# Use Grid from @fluentui/react-northstar without borders

Tags: reactjs, fluentui-react

How to use Grid and Segment in @fluentui/react-northstar without borders or horizontal lines?

```
import { Grid, Segment } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
```

Usage:

```
<Grid columns="repeat(4, 1fr)" rows="50px 150px">
  <Segment
    color="brand"
    content="Header"
    inverted
    styles={{
      gridColumn: 'span 4',
    }}
  />
  <Segment
    color="green"
    content="Menu"
    inverted
    styles={{
      gridColumn: 'span 1',
    }}
  />
  <Segment
    content="Content"
    styles={{
      gridColumn: 'span 3',
    }}
  />
</Grid>
```

The horizontal lines appear around each segments and around the Grid.
The inline style using `border:'none'` or anything relater is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the default box-shadow CSS value currently set to

```
box-shadow: rgb(34 36 38 / 15%) 0px 1px 1px 1px;
```

Add this to your style class.

```
boxShadow: 'none'
```

Comment: Thank you I was overlooking the shadow property.